# Braintree Dropin UI, how to detect Card Type?

Tags: .net, paypal, braintree

I am using Braintree Dropin UI, I need to find out the Card Type like AMEX, VISA, etc.

I am using JS + .NET. This is my Payment request code:

```
var request = new TransactionRequest
                {
                    Amount = Math.Round(amount, 2),
                    PaymentMethodNonce = nonce,
                    MerchantAccountId = merchantAccount,
                    Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
                    {
                        SubmitForSettlement = true
                    }
                };
```

Actually, I need to use specific `merchantAcount` for some specific card type before making the transaction.

Is there any way to get `PaymentMethod` using this `request` or `nonce` from client or `clientToken`.

I can see the PaymentMethod token in Braintree vault.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work as a developer for Braintree. There are [global configurations](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/client-sdk#global-setup) that can be used with the Drop-in integrations to get the card type. The `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback allows you to inspect some basic information about the user's payment method.

This callback intercepts the form submission event so you can add the card type to your form and pass it to your server side code. [More details about the callback are listed here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/client-sdk#payment-method-details). Here's an example of how this might look:

```
 <form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout"> 
   <div id="payment-form"></div> 
   <input type="hidden" id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" value=""> 
   <input type="hidden" id="card_type" name="card_type" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
 </form>
```

Then configure the callback in your client side Braintree setup:

```
braintree.setup(clientTokenFromServer, "dropin", {
    container: "payment-form",
    onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
        var form = document.getElementById("checkout");
        var nonce = document.getElementById("nonce");
        var card_type = document.getElementById("card_type");
        nonce.value = obj.nonce;
        card_type.value = obj.details.cardType;
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

You'll notice that since the submission event is intercepted, I added the payment method nonce to the form and called `submit()` on the form to complete the submission. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CardType from the Transaction response object after the transaction is created. [CardType will be in the CreditCard attribute](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+dotnet/reference/response/transaction#credit_card_details.card_type).

If you're using Braintree's Drop-In UI, it will show you the card type automatically as the user enters the card number.

If you'd like to build your own, [take a look at this JavaScript library for checking card type](https://github.com/braintree/credit-card-type).

### Example

```
var getCardTypes = require('credit-card-type');

var visaCards = getCardTypes('4111');
console.log(visaCards[0].type);  // 'visa'

var ambiguousCards = getCardTypes('6');
console.log(ambiguousCards.length);       // 3
console.log(ambiguousCards[0].niceType);  // 'Discover'
console.log(ambiguousCards[1].niceType);  // 'UnionPay'
console.log(ambiguousCards[2].niceType);  // 'Maestro'
```

Comment: I need CardType before making the transaction and ofcourse it shows in Drop-In UI  but that does not work in my case, I need CardType in my server side code.